# Why are all the Custom Post Types showing in the Recent Posts widget?

Tags: wordpress

I want to show custom post type posts in the recent posts widget. I am using a widget called Advanced Recent Posts Widget to do it. It works on every page except the homepage. On the homepage it shows all of the custom post types posts in the recent posts widget.

I am showing all the custom post type posts on the homepage with this code.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function(WP_Query $query){
    if(is_admin() or is_preview()){
        return;
    }
    // Only add them to the loop on Home/Front-Page
    if((is_home() or is_front_page()) and empty($query->query_vars['suppress_filters'])){
        // This has to be an array so fix it if required
        $post_types = $query->get('post_type');
        if(empty($post_types)) $post_types = array('post');
        elseif(is_string($post_types)) $post_types = array($post_types);
        // Add one or more CPT-s to the loop here (merge old with new)
        $query->set('post_type', array_merge($post_types, array(
            'videos',
            'academic-articles',
            'news-events'
            // 'another_post_type',
            // 'maybe_another_post_type',
    )));
    }
    
    return;
});
```

I want to show all the custom post type posts on the homepage, but only one custom post type in the recent posts widget. It should only show Test in the recent widget and not the other posts.

[image]

I tried to alter the code that shows all the posts on the homepage, but with no succes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the query using the `pre_get_posts` to include all post types on the homepage, but what's happening is that it is changing this or *all* queries on in the homepage.

In your function, you are checking `is_home() or is_front_page()` to make sure it only runs on the homepage. You just need to add one more condition here to check that it is also the **main query**, so that it doesn't affect the query in the widget. You can do this using `$query->is_main_query()`.

So your `if` will now look like this:

```
if( (is_home() or is_front_page()) 
    and $query->is_main_query()  /* <- ADD THIS so it only runs on the main query */
    and empty($query->query_vars['suppress_filters'])){

   /* it's the main query on the homepage so it's ok change the post types... */
}
```